# How to get value from piece of html code with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I just started using python for some web page scraping and **BeautifulSoup** seems to be recommended everywhere.

I have the content like below:

```
<table class="table with-row-highlight table-archive">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="user-tagline ">
          <span class="username " data-avatar="aaaaaaa">player1</span>
          <span class="user-rating">(1357)</span>
          <span class="country-flag-small flag-113" tip="Portugal"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="user-tagline ">
          <span class="username " data-avatar="bbbbbbb">player2</span>
          <span class="user-rating">(1387)</span>
          <span class="country-flag-small flag-70" tip="Indonesia"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="clickable-link text-middle" href="https://www.chess.com/live/game/2249663029?username=belemnarmada" target="_self">
          <div class="pull-left">
            <span class="game-result">1</span>
            <span class="game-result">0</span>
          </div>
          <div class="result">
            <i class="icon-square-minus loss" tip="Lost"></i>
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a class="clickable-link" href="https://www.chess.com/live/game/2249663029?username=belemnarmada" target="_self">30 min</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right">
        <a class="clickable-link text-middle moves" href="https://www.chess.com/live/game/2249663029?username=belemnarmada" target="_self">25</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right miniboard">
        <a class="clickable-link archive-date" href="https://www.chess.com/live/game/2249663029?username=belemnarmada" target="_self">Aug 9, 2017</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    100 <tr></tr> here
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My code stops here, how do I write the python code to loop all the `<tr></tr>` pair and extract all the class for each `<span>` pair in each `<td>` pair?

### edit

I think maybe I didn't explain clearly here, what your code returns are the name of class in that HTML while what I am looking for are the correspondent values, e.g. there is a class `username`, I want to get its value of `player1` and `player2`; there is a class `country-flag-small` `flag-70` I want to get `tip=Indonesia`

Comment: Where is your code please? You have been a member for 7 years so you know how it works for debugging questions.

Comment: How long have you been here, please? wouldn't you provide any constructive answer here like others instead of being mean to someone you don't know?

Comment: it is not rude imo but I apologise if any offence was given. I ask for the code. It is very clear that we expect that for questions that seek debugging help. But if helps please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('someLink')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)


classes = []
for element in soup.find_all(class_=True):
    classes.extend(element["class"])
print(classes)
```

I tested this using your html file and got the following results:

```
['table', 'with-row-highlight', 'table-archive', 'user-tagline', 'username', 'user-rating', 'country-flag-small', 'flag-113', 'user-tagline', 'username', 'user-rating', 'country-flag-small','flag-70', 'clickable-link', 'text-middle', 'pull-left', 'game-result', 'game-result', 'result', 'icon-square-minus', 'loss', 'text-center', 'clickable-link', 'text-right', 'clickable-link', 'text-middle', 'moves', 'text-right', 'miniboard', 'clickable-link', 'archive-date']
```

Do note that you will have to `pip3 install requests` if you haven't already

Also, if you want to test this with a file on your computer, you can do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = open('/path/To/Your/HtmlFile.html', 'r')
lines = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(lines)


classes = []
for element in soup.find_all(class_=True):
    classes.extend(element["class"])
print(classes)
```

Comment: Thank you Jane for the answer, trying to replicate the result here but see some unexpected error here: https://snag.gy/uJRSYo.jpg

Comment: I am able to run your code in Windows now, thank you very much and will update here if there are more questions.

Comment: I think maybe I didn't explain clearly here, what your code returns are the name of class in that HTML while what I am looking for are the correspondent values, e.g. there is a class `"username "`, I want to get its value of `"player1 and player2`; there is a class `"country-flag-small flag-70"` I want to get tip=`"Indonesia"`